# Splitting any SVG path into pieces without changing the shape

Tags: javascript, svg, bezier, vector-graphics

I am new to SVG manipulation using javacript. I would like to split any type of SVG path into *N* number of segments, so that the original shape stays same but with additional points added to the path. I was successfully able to convert a single cubic curve into *N* number of points using the [Bezier JS](http://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/) plugin using the `.getLUT(steps)` function.

And I am able to convert any SVG element into path using [Flatten.js](https://gist.github.com/timo22345/9413158).

Here in the link http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/18441cddeb8fe147b719fab5e30b5d45 a path is splitted seamlessly, But I'm struggling to achieve the same using an existing path in an SVG element in the DOM.

Here is my code:

```
...
<svg id="svg" style="border: 1px solid" width="500" height="500">
   <!--The below is an actual rectangle drawn in illustrator-->
   <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="234" height="125" style="fill:#fff"/>

   <path d="M317,107V231H84V107H317m1-1H83V232H318V106Z" transform="translate(-83 -106)"/>
</svg>

...

<script type="text/javascript">

    //this converts the <rect> and <path> into a more clean path d attribute
    //the above code produces the below d attribute points
    //for <rect> - M0.5, 0.5 L 234.5,0.5 L 234.5, 125.5 L 0.5, 125.5 L 0.5, 0.5 Z
    //for <path> - M234, 1 L 234, 125 L 1, 125 L 1, 1 L 234, 1 m 1, -1 L 0,0 L 0, 126 L 235, 126 L 235,0 Z

    flatten(document.getElementById('svg')); 
    
</script>
```

Comment: If you were successfully able to convert a single cubic curve into N number of points you can try to convert all the commands (exept the move to command (M,m) and the close path command (Z,z)) to cubic bézier.

Comment: So, the plugin Beizer.js converts Cubic curve path that has d = `M100 25 C 10 90 110 100 150 195` 

to `M100 25 76.69 44.82 65.40 61.72 64.07 76.85 70.64 91.36 83.05 106.41 99.25 123.14 117.18 142.72 134.78 166.28 150 195 `

So for dividing do I need to loop to each C points in the path d attribute?

Comment: The second d attribute in your comment looks like a polyline to me.

Comment: It is Cubic curve converted into multiple Lineto point. Please see in the visualizer https://svg-path-visualizer.netlify.app/#M100%2025%2076.69%2044.82%2065.40%2061.72%2064.07%2076.85%2070.64%2091.36%2083.05%20106.41%2099.25%20123.14%20117.18%20142.72%20134.78%20166.28%20150%20195

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the result by getting teh total length of the path using the function `document.getElementById('#path').getTotalLength();` and generating a new d points using document.getElementById('#path').getPointAtLength(i); with the following code

```
the_path = document.getElementById('#path');
let l = the_path.getTotalLength();
let p = the_path.getPointAtLength(0);
let d = `M${p.x} ${p.y}`;
                    
for(let i = (l/num);i<=l;i+=(l/num)){
    p = the_path.getPointAtLength(i);
    d += `L${p.x} ${p.y}`;
}
```

Comment: I've expanded this solution into a [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/jhancock532/pen/OJxwxGR?editors=1010).